# How to Extract First Word of Cell and Copy into another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble extracting the first word of text and copying it into a new cell. This is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim lonstr As String

i = 1

For i = 1 To 500

str = Worksheets("SR060-SR070(2)").Cells(i + 1, "D").Text
longstr = GETFIRSTWORD(str)

Worksheets("SR060-SR070(2)").Cells(i + 1, "U").Value = longstr

Next i 'goes to next row

End Sub


Function GETFIRSTWORD(Text As String, Optional Separator As Variant)

Dim firstword As String

If IsMissing(Separator) Then
 Separator = " "
 End If


firstword = Left(Text, InStr(1, Text, Separator, vbTextCompare))


GETFIRSTWORD = Replace(firstword, Separator, "")

End Function
```

Comment: `GETFIRSTWORD = Split(Text, Separator)(0)`

Comment: Of course I'm just guessing at what kind of "trouble" you're having.  Always helps to be specific ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 500

        With Worksheets("SR060-SR070(2)")
            .Cells(i + 1, "U").Value = GetFirstWord(.Cells(i + 1, "D").Text)
        End With

    Next i 'goes to next row

End Sub


Function GetFirstWord(Text As String, Optional Separator As String="")
    GetFirstWord = Split(Text, Separator)(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get crazy, you can actually replace your entire code with a single `Evaluate()`:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("D1:D500")

Range("U1:U500") = Evaluate("IF(ROW(1:" & r.Count & "),IF(ISERROR(FIND("" ""," & r.Address & "))," & r.Address & ",LEFT(" & r.Address & ",FIND("" ""," & r.Address & ")-1)))")
```